# Unindent does not match any outer indentation level error pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to create a game, but I keep getting an the error 'Unindent does not match any outer indentation level' , preventing my code from being able to run.

I tried changing the order and looking for mistakes, but am unable to spot any

import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

```
#Initialize Package
pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode ((640,600))
pygame.display.set_caption("EduCAUTION")

#Colours init
crushed = (142, 71, 71)
white = (250, 250, 250)

#Text init
pygame.font.init()
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 50)
subtitle = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 25)
normal = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 20)

#Hardware Game Text
hardtitle = myfont.render('Beware Hardware', False, (crushed))
hardrules = subtitle.render('Walk the character to the right answer to clear the path.', False, (75,75,75))
hardQ1 = myfont.render('RAM stands for...', False, (crushed))
Hopt1 = subtitle.render('Random Access Memory', False, (75,75,75))
Hopt2 = subtitle.render('Rotten Apple Monkey', False, (75,75,75))

#Images Init
hardBG = pygame.image.load('comsciBG.jpg')
#Animation
walkRight = [pygame.image.load('R1.png'), pygame.image.load('R2.png'), pygame.image.load('R3.png'), pygame.image.load('R4.png'), pygame.image.load('R5.png'), pygame.image.load('R6.png'), pygame.image.load('R7.png'), pygame.image.load('R8.png'), pygame.image.load('R9.png')]
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('L1.png'), pygame.image.load('L2.png'), pygame.image.load('L3.png'), pygame.image.load('L4.png'), pygame.image.load('L5.png'), pygame.image.load('L6.png'), pygame.image.load('L7.png'), pygame.image.load('L8.png'), pygame.image.load('L9.png')]
left = False
right = False
walkCount = 0
#Constants
x = 60
y = 300
width = 50
height = 50
vel = 25
end = 540

#Variables
game3 = 0

def comSci():
    global game3
    global walkCount
    if walkCount + 1 >= 27:
        walkCount = 0
    win.blit(hardBG, (-5,-20))
    win.blit(hardtitle, (160, 15))
    win.blit(hardrules, (60,80))
    if game3 == 0:
        win.blit(hardQ1, (200, 200))
        pygame.draw.rect(win, white,(15,290,250,50))
        pygame.draw.rect(win, white,(405, 290, 220, 50))
        win.blit(Hopt1, (30, 300))
        win.blit(Hopt2, (420, 300))
    # If facing left
    if left:
        gameWindow.blit(walkLeft[walkCount//3], (x,y))  
        walkCount += 1
    # If facing right
    if right: 
        gameWindow.blit(walkRight[walkCount//3], (x,y))
        walkCount += 1

    pygame.display.update()

run = True
while run:
    #Quit game
    pygame.time.delay(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

     if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > 15:
        x -= vel
        left = True
        right = False

    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 590 - vel - width:  
        x += vel
        left = False
        right = True

    elif keys[pygame.K_UP]  :
        if x >= 200 and y>=40:
            y -= vel
            left = False
             right = False

    elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y < 404 - vel - width:
        y += vel
        left = False
        right = False

    else: 
        left = False
        right = False
        walkCount = 0
    comSci()

#End Game
pygame.quit()
```

The code is suppose to allow an animation to move based on mouse clicks. (Yes, I am aware that the variables are a little innacurate, it is a work in progress). How can I fix this error?

Comment: When there is a syntax error, Python gives you the line where the error is found. Please provide this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its nothing you did, python is having trouble with figuring out indents, to fix it highlight all your work, go to the top of the pages with the stuff like "file edit format" and click format then click tabify region and press ok

Comment: Did this help you?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will solve it, but the if here:

```py
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > 15:
    x -= vel
    left = True
    right = False
```

The `if` is one space ahead the rest of the indentation block, that could be the cause if you're using Python3.+